# Working with "SML of new jersey"

Tags: sml, smlnj

I download "SML of new jersey" for windows vista.

I work on ML file which call "a.ml" in libary c.

Now I want to load all the commands in the file to the interpter, but I don't succsses.

I tried (use "c:\a.ml");

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `\a` in the string is interpreted as an escape sequence (specifying the bell character) - not a backslash followed by an a. You need to escape the backslash with another backslash for it to be interpreted as a literal backslash. I.e.:

```
use "c:\\a.ml";
```

You can also use forward slashes instead of backslashes to avoid having to escape anything.

Also note that if you invoke the interpreter from within the directory the ml file is in, you don't need to specify a directory at all, i.e. `use "a.ml";` will do in that case.

Comment: Thank you, I did what you write, but It still don't work,
In a.scm, I have just one line: fn () => 1;
and It need to printout: val it = fn : unit -> int
But I don't get anything, just "=". Why?

Comment: @Tom: If you get a `=` that means you forgot the semicolon (or possibly you forgot to close the string - either way it means the interpreter is waiting for you to finish the current expression).